# Jquery, 405 error from Ajax call but the item is created

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I keep getting a 405 error upon a POST method

```
$.ajax({
    url: mistergoUrl,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: body,
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function () {
        // TODO: find a cleaner way to get the last route
        $.getJSON(mistergoUrl)
            .done(function (data) {
                data = resolveReferences(data);
                window.location.replace("Route.html?id=" + data.last().RouteId);
            });
    },
    error: function (httpObj, result) {
        Console.log(result);
        Console.log(httpObj);
    }
});
```

On the server, the request is valid, is processed and returned as expected, but the Ajax function keeps giving back a 405 error...

This is the asp.net code

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(RoutePostModel postdata)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    _routeService.Add(postdata);
    var route = _routeService.GetAll().Last();
    var url = Url.Route("DefaultApi", new {controller = "Routes", id = route.RouteId});
    return Created(url, route);
}
```

Does anybody know why and how this could happen? any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/216493) help you?

Comment: Thanks but no, it doesn't seem to get me any further. :(

Comment: is there any GET method in the same controller?

Comment: Yes, one with no parameters, one with one INT, and one with two Ints